# Can i access the response context of a view tested without the test client?

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing

I have a function which i call from a unittest. From setting some debug traces i know the function worked like a charm and has all the values correctly prepared for return.

This is what my testcode looks like (see where my ipdb.set_trace() is ):

```
@override_settings(REGISTRATION_OPEN=True)
def test_confirm_account(self):
    """ view that let's a user confirm account creation and username
        when loggin in with social_auth """    
    request = self.factory.get('')
    request.user = AnonymousUser()
    request.session={}
    request.session.update({self.pipename:{'backend':'facebook',
                                           'kwargs':{'username':'Chuck Norris','response':{'id':1}}}})

    # this is the function of which i need the context:
    response = confirm_account(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.context['keytotest'],'valuetotest')
```

From what i know from [this part of the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#testing-responses), i would be able to access response.context when i have used the testing client. But when i try to access response.context like i did it, i get this:

> AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'context'

Is there a way to get the special HttpResponse object of the client, without using the client?

Answer (score 12):

The RequestFactory does not touch the Django middleware, and as such, you will not generate a context (i.e. no ContextManager middleware).

If you want to test the context, you should use the test client. You can still manipulate the construction of the request in the test client either using *mock* or simply saving your session ahead of time in the test, such as:

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()
session = c.session
session['backend'] = 'facebook'
session['kwargs'] = {'username':'Chuck Norris','response':{'id':1}}
session.save()
```

Now when you load the view with the test client, you'll be using the session as you set it, and when you use `response = c.get('/yourURL/')`, you can then reference the response context using `response.context` as desired.

Answer (score 6):

The "response.context" is incorrect for new django versions but you can use response.context_data to get the same context that passed to TemplateResponse.

Comment: You're downvoted, but this is correct.  `response.context` is a `ContextList` object whereas `response.context_data` is a dictionary structured like the `Context` instance passed to the template.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old post, I suppose this tip can be of help. You can look into using `TemplateResponse` (or `SimpleTemplateResponse`) which can be substituted for `render` or `render_to_response`.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/template-response/) has more on this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You have to patch render.

I'm using pytest-django

```
class Test:
    def context(self, call_args):
        args, kwargs = call_args
        request_mock, template, context = args
        return context

    @patch('myapplication.views.render')
    def test_(self, mock_render, rf):
        request = rf.get('fake-url')
        view(request)
        context = self.context(mock_render.call_args)

        keytotest = 'crch'
        assert keytotest == context['keytotest']
```

Answer (score -6):

context (sic!) can be found in Response class. As you see it says it's **HTTP**Response you get back from the view function. This happened because you've called it directly. Call this function via test client and it will be okay.

```
response = client.get('/fobarbaz/')
response.context
```

Comment: Calling it via the test client doesn't give me full control over the contruction of the request. I explicitely asked if it is possible without the client.

Comment: I'm manipulating session using built-in client in my tests (look at client.session). Is that what you call request contruction control? If so, reconsider your downvote.

Comment: No, it's not. A session is information about a certain user stored on the serverside, the request is what a client sends to the server to request a server response. The response context (that i was asking for) is only used for testing and contains information about how the server created the response (ie. which templates have been used). It is not the same as the request context and not the same as the session.